# KeyError on Linux but not Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, keyerror

I have a bizarre situation:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = {}
        self.data = data
        old_data_name = "SOURCE" # self.data[old_data_name] = a list of values
        try:
           self.data[old_data_name] = [1,2,3,4]
        except Exception as e:
           print(str(e))
        new_data_name = "NEW" # a name
        self.data[new_data_name] = numpy.mean(self.data[old_data_name])
```

So this code works perfectly on windows - I have debugged this statement by statement and verified it.
When I deploy my code on to a linux server. It throws me a `KeyError: old_data_name`

I am sure the data is coming in to the point where the key error should not occur.
Why does python behave so differently on Linux and Windows?

Comment: Are you sure that problem in OS? What versions of pythons you use on both machines?

Comment: Both versions are 3.6 - The linux was skipping the try code altogether. No exceptions nothing. It works fine in windows. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 pip3 python3. Windows env is 10

Comment: Also you check `old_data_name` in your try-catch block but after that you just get it in `numpy.mean(self.data[old_data_name])`.

Comment: @LevZakharov The problem is not checking. The problem is that in Ubuntu it skips the try: code altogether (I think this is a platform specific bug)

Comment: `KeyError: old_data_name` implies that your code is doing the equivalent of `self.data["old_data_name"]`. KeyError gives the value of the key that couldn't be found, *not* the name of the variable it was stored in.

Comment: @BoarGules It was KeyError : "Source" I just wrote it like that for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first impression was a version mismatch:

> @Basic  Thanks to Basic The issue was indeed version mismatch. Visual
>   Studio on windows defaulted to 3.6 and Ubuntu was forcing 3.5.2 Din't
>   know there were such huge breaking changes just from a small revision
>   from python. Seems like a big mess.

But upon further investigation. It revealed that version python 3.5.2 has weird way of reading json files compared to 3.6.6
Essentially the way I loaded my data meant that it self references properties that once loaded. for eg:

```
{properties: {"stuff": "do this", "stuff2": "do another with @stuff" }}
```

My code was looking for stuff in stuff2 when stuff was never loaded

**Python version 3.5.2 has no specific order in which it loads json data to dicts** which causes issues.

Python 3.6.6 fixes this.

Comment: The Try should only ever skip if there's an error. You could take the try/except out and force python to fail at that point, but the error message you're getting printed out should tell you exactly what the problem is. You might also try printing out `self.data` the line before you try to assign a value to it. Finally, are you definitely running the same version of Python on both environments? And do they have all the same packages installed?

Comment: Im checking it now. Visual studio forced execution via 3.6 and linux was defaulting to 3.5.2. Perhaps this could be the culprit. and No there are no errors or exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You should not get values by `old_data_name` from `self.data` outside the try-catch block, because if there is no such key you print error and than trying to get something by this key. It's wrong. You should write like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = {}
        self.data = data
        old_data_name = "SOURCE" # self.data[old_data_name] = a list of values
        try:
            self.data[old_data_name] = [1,2,3,4]
            new_data_name = "NEW" # a name
            self.data[new_data_name] = numpy.mean(self.data[old_data_name])
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Comment: I have done as you suggested and still get KeyError on Ubuntu(my deployment) but not on Windows

Comment: Ok, what do you pass as `data` to your constructor method?

Comment: its a dict {old_data_name: [1,2,3]} - the funny thing is Im debugging on Visual Studio and I can see the data coming in. But  Linux still throws a KeyError. Perhaps I should try debugging the data source in Linux

Comment: Yep, try to debug it on your  Linux server. I'm sure that you missed something and problem not in platform.